# Make new column(s) from existing column(s), where an input file specifies which columns to make/use

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `panda dataframe` that contains a multi index, and a bunch of columns.

I want to add new columns into this `dataframe` by adding (subtracting) together 2 or more existing columns in the `dataframe`.

What the new column names are, which columns should be used, and whether they should be added or subtracted is specified via a separate input `csv` file.

**For example:**

my **initial dataframe**:

```
                 col1  col2   col3   col4
index1  index2
  A       X       10    100    50     20
  B       X       10    200    50     20
  C       X       10    300    50     20
```

the **column instruction csv/dataframe**

```
                       Factor
newCol      existingCol
  newCol1       col1     1
  newCol1       col2     1
  newCol2       col2     1
  newCol2       col3    -1
  newCol2       col4    -1
```

This file says to create 2 new columns called `newCol1` and `newCol2`.  To make `newCol1` add the data in `col1` and `col2`.  To make `newCol2` take the data in `col2` and subtract both `col3` and `col4`.

The net **resulting dataframe** should look like:

```
                 col1  col2   col3   col4  newCol1  newCol2
index1  index2
  A       X       10    100    50     20    110       30
  B       X       10    200    50     20    210      130 
  C       X       10    300    50     20    310      230
```

I have no knowledge before reading the data and column files what the column names will or how they are to be combined.

If the `dataframe` needs to be `"deindexed"` to do this that is fine, I can always reindex it again after the new column data has been added.

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I will go about it:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

s = StringIO('''    index1  index2          col1  col2   col3   col4
  A       X       10    100    50     20
  B       X       10    200    50     20
  C       X       10    300    50     20 
''')


df1 = pd.read_csv(s, sep='\s+')

s = StringIO('''newCol      existingCol                      Factor
  newCol1       col1     1
  newCol1       col2     1
  newCol2       col2     1
  newCol2       col3    -1
  newCol2       col4    -1
''')
df2 = pd.read_csv(s, sep='\s+')

def add_new_cols(df1, df2):
    for new_col in set(df2.newCol):
        df_temp = df2[df2.newCol == new_col]
        df_temp.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

        df1[new_col] = 0
        for row_ind in range(df_temp.shape[0]):
             df1[new_col] += df_temp.loc[row_ind, 'Factor']*df1.loc[:, df_temp.loc[row_ind, 'existingCol']]

        print(df_temp)
        print('___')

add_new_cols(df1, df2)
```

Modifies df1 to the desired form. Although this is not the most efficient way but gets the job done.

**Better Solution**

First create the string representing the formula and then use eval on first data frame to apply this formula.

```
# Achieving the same using .eval
for new_col in set(df2.newCol):
    print(new_col)

    df_temp = df2[df2.newCol == new_col]
    df_temp.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

    formula_ = '0'
    for row_ind in range(df_temp.shape[0]):
        if df_temp.loc[row_ind, "Factor"] >= 0:
            formula_ += '+' + f'{df_temp.loc[row_ind, "Factor"]}*{df_temp.loc[row_ind, "existingCol"]}'
        else:
            formula_ +=  f'{df_temp.loc[row_ind, "Factor"]}*{df_temp.loc[row_ind, "existingCol"]}'
    print(formula_)

    df1.eval(f'{new_col}={formula_}', inplace=True)
```

The desired output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, i'm very new to python so you've given me quite a few new things to investigate.

Comment: Most welcome dear, that’s why StackOverflow is here. If it did the job please accept it as final answer ;)

Comment: @[Pankaj Joshi] I have upticked your answer,  but I belive it contains an error where you have mixed integer and string indexing into the dataframe.  I replaced `df_temp.loc[row_ind, 'columnName']` with `df_temp.loc[row_ind, df_temp.columns.get_loc('columnName')]`   You might want to edit.

Comment: @Andrewfreestuff; Thanks. which pandas version are you using. On 0.23.4 it's working without error.

Comment: @[Pankaj Joshi] ah, that might be it  I am on a very old version, 0.20.something